# Handling 2 Views with 2 UIPanGestures.

Tags: ios

I have one view (A) with its UIPanGestureRecognizer (PAN_A) attached and second view (B) that is *subview* of A and has it own UIPanGestureRecognizer (PAN_B) too. View A is delegate of PAN_A and B is delegate of PAN_B

I'm having hard time making them working correctly.

I would expect that when `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` of B returns `false` automatically the event is passed down to A and recognized by PAN_A... but this is not happening at all :/

I've also tried any combination of `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` disabling it for A when I need the gesture to be enabled on B... but again it is not working. The gesture seems to be always trapped by PAN_B

**Depending on some conditions I need to have the gesture recognized and handled by PAN_A or recognized and handled by PAN_B** I would like to have a sort of switch that just turn off recognition for the view B when it is not needed.

Which is the best way to go if you need to handle touches in different ways on the same hierarchy? Should I handle all the gestures at ROOT level (in my example with the PAN_A of the A view) and pass the gesture information up to B "manually", when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using gestureRecognized delegate something like this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
//Maybe extra validation
if ([touch.view isDescendantOfView:yourSubView]) {
    return NO;
}
    return YES;
}
```

Or yo can handle with firstResponder method, viewA.firstResponder after validation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `aView` and `bView` being the delegates for `panA` and `panB`, can you try making both `panA` and `panB` be delegates of their common view controller? That way the gesture recognizer delegate methods will be triggered by both the pan gestures and will work like you expect them to.

Here's some sample code that worked for me: (In this example, all the connections for the gesture recognizers and the views have been done by  storyboard, but the `ViewController` is delegate for both `panA` and `panB`.) The `panAActive` is the "switch" that you want. If you flip it `panA` and `panB` will work alternately.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *aView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPanGestureRecognizer *panA;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPanGestureRecognizer *panB;

@property BOOL panAActive;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.panAActive = NO;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.panA) {
        return self.panAActive;
    }
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.panB) {
        return !self.panAActive;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ((gestureRecognizer == self.panA && otherGestureRecognizer == self.panB) ||
        (gestureRecognizer == self.panB && otherGestureRecognizer == self.panA)){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)aPanned:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"aPanned");
}

- (IBAction)bPanned:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"bPanned");
}
```